# Need to get data recursively in GraphQl

Tags: neo4j, graphql

Is it possible to get data in one call for parent and child in GraphQL

Sample data set

```
============================
|   Id     |  Expression |
===========================
|    1     | N_2 + N_3   |
===========================
|    2     | N_4 + N_5   |
===========================
|    3     | N_6 + N_7   |
===========================
```

So basically what I want is in a single call like 
I want to query Id - 1 and fetch it's expression `N_2 + N_3` 
parse `N_2 + N_3` to get `2` and `3` and get the data for `2` and `3` from 
table.

I want to get this in a single database hit.

I have read about nested queries but I guess it hits the database again
for nested queries.

Kindly let me know if there is any way or Graph databases like Neo4j is the only solution for such problem.

I have achieved this in Neo4j but for this I have used SQLAlchemy to fetch the data and then created it's child in the list of dicts like

```
{id:1, child: [1, 2, 4, 5]}
```

Is is possible even in Neo4j to achieve this without using the SQLAlchemy problem.

Comment: How are you storing data in Neo4j? Are you creating a node with a particular id and then storing these values in child property?

Comment: @Raj Yes, currently I am using this methods as mentioned already in my question.

Comment: Okay, You can model this data in Neo4j with Child relationship. And get two levels nodes in single query.

Comment: I have done the same thing. I am asking for alternative. Please read my question and let me know if it's not clear I will edit it.

Comment: Your question is clear. You have added a list of the child as a property on a node, a relationship is different from property. Instead of creating child property with value 1,2,4,5 create separate nodes for each and add a relationship between those.  I assume you know what are relationships in Neo4j.

Comment: You can share how you modelled data in Neo4j with some picture to make it clear.